# Merge a 1d and a 2d array based on shared string value and use default values where data is missing

Tags: php, arrays, merge, mapping, default-value

I want to merge a 2-dimensional array with a flat array of contiguous dates to generate an array of user scores for all dates.  Not all dates have a corresponding row with a score, so the value should default to zero.

User data array:

```
$data = [
    ['New User', '2017-07-10', '12'],
    ['New User', '2017-07-11', '6'], 
    ['New User', '2017-07-13', '19']
];
```

Week dates array:

```
$datesArr = [
    '2017-07-10', 
    '2017-07-11', 
    '2017-07-12', 
    '2017-07-13', 
    '2017-07-14', 
    '2017-07-15', 
    '2017-07-16', 
    '2017-07-17'
];
```

Desired output:

```
[
    ['New User', '2017-07-10', '12'],
    ['New User', '2017-07-11', '6'], 
    ['New User', '2017-07-12', '0'],
    ['New User', '2017-07-13', '19']
    ['New User', '2017-07-14', '0'],
    ['New User', '2017-07-15', '0'],
    ['New User', '2017-07-16', '0'],
    ['New User', '2017-07-17', '0'],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use the date strings as array keys:

```
<?php
$users = [
    ['New User', '2017-07-10', 12],
    ['New User', '2017-07-11', 6],
    ['New User', '2017-07-13', 19]
];
$dates = [
    '2017-07-10',
    '2017-07-11',
    '2017-07-12',
    '2017-07-13',
    '2017-07-14',
    '2017-07-15',
    '2017-07-16',
    '2017-07-17'
];
$output = [];
// create new users array with dates as keys
array_walk($users, function($user) use (&$output) {
    $output[$user[1]] = $user;
});
// iterate over dates array to fill in as requred
array_walk($dates, function($date) use (&$output) {
    if (!array_key_exists($date, $output)) {
        $output[$date] = ['New User', $date, 0];
    }
});
print_r(array_values($output));
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => New User
            [1] => 2017-07-10
            [2] => 12
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => New User
            [1] => 2017-07-11
            [2] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => New User
            [1] => 2017-07-13
            [2] => 19
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => New User
            [1] => 2017-07-10
            [2] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => New User
            [1] => 2017-07-11
            [2] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => New User
            [1] => 2017-07-12
            [2] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => New User
            [1] => 2017-07-13
            [2] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => New User
            [1] => 2017-07-14
            [2] => 0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => New User
            [1] => 2017-07-15
            [2] => 0
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => New User
            [1] => 2017-07-16
            [2] => 0
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => New User
            [1] => 2017-07-17
            [2] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have tried your logic but some dates are repeating in the array like `2017-07-10, 2017-07-11, 2017-07-13`.

Comment: @Mr.Happy Sorry, my bad, obviously I used the wrong index, `2` instead of `1` for the date in the first iteration! Fixed in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be helpful, Here we are using `array_column` and `foreach` to achieve desired output.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/833568)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$data = array(
    array('0' => 'New User', '1' => '2017-07-10', '2' => '12'), 
    array('0' => 'New User', '1' => '2017-07-11', '2' => '6'), 
    array('0' => 'New User', '1' => '2017-07-13', '2' => '19'));
$datesArr = array(
    '0' => '2017-07-10', 
    '1' => '2017-07-11', 
    '2' => '2017-07-12', 
    '3' => '2017-07-13', 
    '4' => '2017-07-14', 
    '5' => '2017-07-15', 
    '6' => '2017-07-16', 
    '7' => '2017-07-17');

$datesPresent=array_column($data, 1);
$result=array();
foreach($datesArr as $date)
{
    if(!in_array($date, $datesPresent))
    {
        $result[]=array('New User',$date,0);
    }
    else
    {
        $result[]=current($data);
        next($data);
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like that?

```
<?php
$data = array(array('0' => 'New User', '1' => '2017-07-10', '2' => '12'), array('0' => 'New User', '1' => '2017-07-11', '2' => '6'), array('0' => 'New User', '1' => '2017-07-13', '2' => '19'));

$datesArr = array('0' => '2017-07-30', '1' => '2017-07-11', '2' => '2017-07-12', '3' => '2017-07-13', '4' => '2017-07-14', '5' => '2017-07-15', '6' => '2017-07-16', '7' => '2017-07-17');

$new_array = array();
foreach($datesArr as $date)
{
   foreach($data as $d)
   {
        if($date == $d[1])
        {
            $temp = $d;
            break;
        }
   }

   $temp = !isset($temp) ? array('0' => 'New User','1' => $date,'2' => 0) : $temp;
   $new_array[] = $temp;
}

var_dump($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to use array_search here:

```
$data = array(array('0' => 'New User', '1' => '2017-07-10', '2' => '12'), array('0' => 'New User', '1' => '2017-07-11', '2' => '6'), array('0' => 'New User', '1' => '2017-07-13', '2' => '19'));
$datesArr = array('0' => '2017-07-10', '1' => '2017-07-11', '2' => '2017-07-12', '3' => '2017-07-13', '4' => '2017-07-14', '5' => '2017-07-15', '6' => '2017-07-16', '7' => '2017-07-17');

$newData = array();
foreach ($datesArr as $value) {
  $key = array_search($value, array_column($data, 1));
  if ($key===false) {
    $newData[]=array('0' => 'New User', '1' => $value, '2' => 0);
  }else{
    $newData[]=$data[$key];
  }
}
print_r($newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a lookup array of your first array by assigning first level keys from the column of dates with `array_column()`.  Then as you iterate the array of dates, you can quickly check if the user's score exists.  If the date does not map to a date with scores, fallback to default values.

The below script assumes that all of the dates in the scores array will be present in the second array of dates (or that you don't want scores if they fall outside of the array of dates).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/l3cD6))

```
$lookup = array_column($data, null, 1);
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($v) => $lookup[$v] ?? ['New User', $v, 0],
        $datesArr
    )
);
```

The above should outperform any alternative script that uses `in_array()` calls, `array_search()` calls, or nested "brute force" loops.